# Bamboo Junit Report with Percentage

Tags: junit, report, bamboo

in my bambo Plan i can see via JUnit Report, how many 
Existing Failures, Fixed or New Failures i have with the Numbers.

What i want is, to get the Percentage of it instead of the numbers.

An example url would be:

*Lets say: 10.000 Tests tested
5 % Existing Failures, 5% Fixed 10% New Failures*

I have tryed to use any plugins: 
Did not found any!